# Automaticly put any new video from a folder into an After Effects composition and render it

Tags: video-processing, encoder, after-effects

Is there a solution to do the following:
1-User put videos in a specific folder
2-After Effect detect automatically any new video, put it in a composition, apply keying effect, create an image background layer, render the video
3-Adobe media encoder detect the new rendered video, compress the video into many formats and upload them to ftp server

Comment: You're going to have tough time getting an answer because A) You have not shown any effort in solving the problem yourself (example code), and B) you haven't given enough information. But I'll start some sort of ball rolling by asking what operating system are you on, or must this be cross-platform?

Comment: A- In fact i did, and I am not sure if any script code need to be used. B- Is there any points that wasn't clear enough? we are using windows, its for an internal project to fasten the production in our studio

Comment: To simplify: Is after effect able to detect a change to a folder? and apply an automatic saved script (like Photoshop action)

Comment: Re: A) "**shown** any effort" -- I'm not saying you haven't made effort, there just isn't anything to see in your post, and stackoverflow requires showing examples, not asking generally for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

See this, which sums up the capabilities of AE being able to "watch folders": http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html  As far as being able to 'attach a script' to that action, no, that's not really the way it can work.

But of course you can devise a way to use an external 'engine' (shell script, batch script, applescript, etc.) that does the 'watching', and gets AE to run a specfic script when something happens. Most people would like that capability to be in the AE binary-running as a flag (-script scriptToRun, or something like that), but unfortunately that isn't possible. ExtendScript can 'talk' to different apps, which gets rather involved, but it's possible. And you need a higher-level script to call those scripts, like using AppleScript (sorry, I know, you're Windows) to tell AE to run a script, render, etc. Batch scripts would be an equiv. in Windows, I'm also a fan of AutoIt, which is v. powerful.

Comment: It seems that the "watch folders" can be used o run a rendering farm, so it seems there is no easy solution. I wish adobe will let us in the future integrate the AE engine with our apps by running automated scripts or maybe as saas online. Thanks